# How do I debug in VS Code using C++. I keep on getting errors

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've searched up so much on how to debug on VS Code using C++, but still did come with a resolution. Here are the errors that I am receiving.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8V80.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS6OE.jpg)

[image]

Comment: you have to find out why you want to compile your program into the `.vscode` folder, select the `.cpp` file before you press `F5`

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that it cannot find .exe under the provided path. Provide the correct path under "program" key.

Comment: The program file (.exe) is on my desktop in a folder with other .cpp and .h files. Would I need to include something like this C:/Users/username/Desktop/Login_Register_Bank/ATM.exe?

Comment: I also have a .sh file that compiles everything and runs the entire program for me. Do you think that is causing an error? I will post the pictures up